# Python turtle - how to draw spider net

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I need to draw the following spider web using python.

[Spider web complete - what I need to draw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhS89.png)

I've googled my way to turtle, and have made the following

[Spider web incomplete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDWjn.png)

So, what I need help with is how to make the straight lines into curves. I've been trying with `circle()`, but can't get it to work the way I want. Any tips, either with or without turtle is appreciated

Comment: It seems that drawing curves between points is quite difficult with a turtle, why is it that you need to do this?

Comment: Just some homework for a beginner python class I'm taking. Really random excercise that we haven't learned in class. So if anyone's got any ideas without turtle they are more than welcome 

Comment: Does it specify only that you should draw that some way, not that it has to be using a turtle?

Comment: That's correct! Just need to draw it somehow using any kind of python code. Perferably simple code, as it is the first home assignment in a beginners course.

Comment: Is the course you're taking somehow related to a maths course? The maths required to draw something like this is not exactly trivial

Comment: No, it's just an elective beginners course in python. I have solved my problem now however, thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 0):

Theorem: There is only one true parabola in 2 dimension space, `a*x^2 + b*x + C` [Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hoh4TmPzu1w). From this, it follows that what you are drawing are multiple instances of the same parabola, with an increasingly higher value of C, starting from `C=0`; then you rotate it around the origin, and draw a copy of the parabola for any angle corresponding to +/- PI/4 from the original angle. For each parabola, you draw only the portion which is comprised between `y=0` or `x=0`, whichever is the case, and `y=-x` or `y=x`, as appropriate. If you post some coding of this and it does not work, we can help you fix it.

You should define a function that, given as input the X values and an angle `theta`, plus a, b, and c accordingly to the parabola you want to use, computes the corresponding Y values of the parabola Y = a*x^2 + b*x +c rotated by the angle `theta`. The value for `b` will be 0, in your case, because the parabola whose axis is parallel to the `y` axis and whose minimum/maximum is in `x=0,y=0` has a C value of 0.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response! I was very confused with your response :p Quite new to python. Anyway, I've solved my problem :-) Have a nice weekend!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to draw this approximation using Python turtle and the `turtle.circle()` command:

[image]

I also used `turle.forward()` & `turtle.backward()`, as well as `turtle.heading()` & `turtle.setheading()`, to draw radii.  I used `turtle.left()`, `turtle.right()` and `turtle.sety()` to position the turtle.  And I threw in `screen.setworldcoordinates()` to adjust the aspect ratio to create that slightly flattened look of the original.

Assuming the above is close enough, the key is to take the time to understand what happens when you supply *negative* values for the circle's radius and `extent=` arguments.

If you don't do so first, I'll post the (two dozen lines of) code after your assignment has probably come due.

Comment: Hi, thanks! I was able to make it work using circle() and left(). The drawing isn't perfect as circle() can only produce perfect circles and not ovals, but it's good enough for my assignment. Thanks for the help anyway!